# How to change IdentityServer OIDC discovery endpoint base url?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

IdentityServer4 provides an OIDC discovery endpoint, which can be used to retrieve metadata about the authorization server including the Token Endpoint. The discovery endpoint is available via /.well-known/openid-configuration **relative to the base address of your Token Server**. For example, if we run the application locally and perform a GET request to the following endpoint:

```
https://localhost:44354/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

We will then be presented with the following JSON schema below:

```
{
    "issuer": "https://localhost:44354",
    "jwks_uri": "https://localhost:44354/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
    "authorization_endpoint": "https://localhost:44354/connect/authorize",
    "token_endpoint": "https://localhost:44354/connect/token",
    "userinfo_endpoint": "https://localhost:44354/connect/userinfo",
    "end_session_endpoint": "https://localhost:44354/connect/endsession",
    
    // code omitted for brevity
}
```

Based on "The discovery endpoint is available via /.well-known/openid-configuration **relative to the base address of your Token Server**" clause, I am wondering how can I change this endpoint's base address. Is it possible in an ASP.NET Core application?

Comment: Any updates or solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Won't help the op, but for others...

I'm not sure that it's a documented approach, but this works (place **before** UseIdentityServer):

```
    app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
    {
        var serverUrls = ctx.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IServerUrls>();
        serverUrls.Origin = serverUrls.Origin = "https://yourneworigin";
        await next();
    });

    app.UseIdentityServer();
```

I'm using it as a temporary workaround until our reverse proxy gets configured correctly.

For those that are here because of reverse proxy issues, Duende have this documentation:
https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/deployment/proxies/

Note a couple of important facets:

- Use UseForwardedHeaders needs to be at the start of the pipeline
- The reverse proxy needs configuring to send the "forwarded for" headers

Comment: Works fine for chenge base url in discovery document !!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible to change this.

If you look at the source code [here](https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer/blob/main/src/IdentityServer/Constants.cs), you see that it is a constant:

However, this GitHub issue and the issues it links to, might give you some alternatives:

[How to customize the route path?](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/593)

Answer (score 0):

As per this [answer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4631#issuecomment-690039155), below is a code example.
NOTE: make sure to put this middleware before `UseIdentityServer()`.

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    // context.Request.Protocol = "https"; // this didn't work so I use the following:
    context.Request.IsHttps = true;
    context.Request.Host = new HostString("my-domain.com", 12345);
    context.Request.PathBase = new PathString("/api/auth");

    return next();
});

app.UseIdentityServer();
```